# Use getter as parameter in method

Tags: java, function, generics, variadic-functions, getter

I have multiple different classes Class1, Class2, Class3.
Each class has different variables and getters for them.

```
public class Class1 {
 private String var1_1;
 private String var1_2;
 private String var1_3;

 public String getVar1_1() { return var1_1;}
 public String getVar1_2() { return var1_2;}
 public String getVar1_3() { return var1_3;}
}

public class Class2 {
 private String var2_1;
 private String var2_2;
 private String var2_3;

 public String getVar2_1() { return var2_1;}
 public String getVar2_2() { return var2_2;}
 public String getVar2_3() { return var2_3;}
}

public class Class3 {
 private String var3_1;
 private String var3_2;
 private String var3_3;

 public String getVar3_1() { return var3_1;}
 public String getVar3_2() { return var3_2;}
 public String getVar3_3() { return var3_3;}
}
```

How can I write method which takes List of objects and getters(functions) as a method parameters?
For example:

```
List<Class1> list1 = //doesn't matter
List<Class2> list2 = //doesn't matter
List<Class3> list3 = //doesn't matter
generateRows(list1, Class1::getVar1_1, Class1::getVar1_3);
generateRows(list2, Class2::getVar2_1, Class2::getVar2_2, Class2::getVar2_3);
generateRows(list3, Class3::getVar3_1, Class3::getVar3_2);
```

Method

```
public void generateRows(List<T> list, /*???Something???*/... getters) {
 for(T object: list) {
  /*How to use getters to print?*/
  /*System.out.println(obj.firtsGetter())*/
 }
}
```

What I should write instead of `???Something???`. Something like `Function<T, String>` or `Consumer<T>`? And how can I use getters in method?

Comment: you understand that, in order to cal (non-static) getters, you'll need an instance of the object first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the method calls in a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). A [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), or another [FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) might do the trick as well, depending on your needs.

Then you need to have your method accept varargs of this function.

```
  public static <T> void generateRows(List<T> list, Function<T, String>... getters) {
    for (T object : list) {
      for (Function<T, String> getter : getters) {
        System.out.println(getter.apply(object));
      }
    }
  }
```

Function will accept argument of type `T` and return a `String`. `T` can be anything - `Class1`, `Class2`, etc., as long you can return a string from this object - that means to have a getter method returning `String` in your case.

Answer (score -1):

First you can defined a interface eg:

```
 interface  Get{
    String getVar1();
     String getVar2();
     String getVar3();
 }
```

Second All of classes implemente it:

```
 class Class2 implements Get{
    private String var2_1;
    private String var2_2;
    private String var2_3;

    public String getVar1() { return var2_1;}
    public String getVar2() { return var2_2;}
    public String getVar3() { return var2_3;}
}
```

Third:

```
   public void generateRows(List<T> list, Get ...getters) {
        for(T object: list) {
            /*How to use getters to print?*/
            /*System.out.println(obj.firtsGetter())*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `generateRows` signature is incorrect. - you are missing a type argument declaration. Also why providing both `List<T>` and `Get...` as arguments, they can't be used together as it currently is. `Get` methods don't have arguments and we don't know anything about `T`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).